# Use Swing form as template for others

Tags: java, forms, swing

I'm very new to all things Java. I'm just trying to create a simple application with multiple forms. I have created a Swing form that will be the basis for all other forms. I am then trying to instantiate the generic Swing form and add components particular to whichever form I am then creating.

I am having particular trouble adding a JTable on one of the forms to a layout.

Here is my minimal code example:

The template form:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class FormLayout extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    

    public FormLayout() throws SQLException {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 850, 800);

            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            
            GroupLayout gl_contentPane = new GroupLayout(contentPane);
            gl_contentPane.setHorizontalGroup(
                gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup())
            );
            gl_contentPane.setVerticalGroup(
                gl_contentPane.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(gl_contentPane.createSequentialGroup())
            );
            
            contentPane.setLayout(gl_contentPane);
            //gl_contentPane.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    
        }
    }
```

The calling class:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Main extends FormLayout {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public Main() throws SQLException{
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        FormLayout frame = new FormLayout();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    
    public void MainForm() throws SQLException{
        String str = "select * from tblEndoscopy";
        ResultSet rs = Bquery.resultQuery(str);
        JTable table = new JTable(Bquery.buildTableModel(rs));
        // HOW DO I ADD THIS JTABLE TO THE TEMPLATE
        // FORM i.e. TO THE GROUPED PANEL?
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) I suggest moving the one question in a code comment, to above all the source code.

Comment: [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)